# Найти прямую, пересекающую наибольшее число отрезков

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Вспомнилась задача, которую приходилось решать в самом первом семестре обучения в университете.

**Вход:**
Множество отрезков, каждый задается двумя точками. (координата начала - координата конца)
**Выход:**
Коэффициенты в уравнении прямой, пересекающей наибольшее число заданных отрезков. (Ax + By + C = 0)

Насколько помню, на тот момент я решал задачу так:

1. Находил область на плоскости, в которой лежали все заданные отрезки.
2. Расширял данную область в каждом направлении на небольшое значение. (пусть это будет 5)
3. Перебирал все прямые, которые мог построить в данной области (от одного края до другого), проверял, сколько отрезков при этом прямая пересекает.
4. Останавливался в тот момент, когда находил прямую, пересекающую все заданные отрезки, либо когда перебирать уже было нечего.

А какие у вас мысли по поводу алгоритма решения данной задачи?

Comment: *"Перебирал все прямые, которые мог построить в данной области"* - их же бесконечное множество. Как вы их перебирали? )

Comment: Да, тут небольшая неточность. Я проходил только по целым числам)

Comment: Вот вам и первая промашка - прямых там бесконечное множество. // Минус не мой, если что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать решать методом, аналогичным [алгоритму Хафа.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0)

Для каждого отрезка известно семейство прямых в `rho-theta` пространстве, которые его пересекают.

Создаём двумерным массив-аккумулятор `Н` - сетку по `rho` и по `theta` нужной дискретности. Для каждого отрезка добавляем единицы в те ячейки Н, которые соответствуют уравнениям прямых, пересекающих отрезок. Для классического Хафа точка задаёт кривую дугу, здесь же будет изогнутая полоса.

После обработки отрезков находим ячейку аккумулятора `Н` с наибольшим значением. Она соответствует искомой прямой